# GStreamer Element Dependencies: How to connect playbin to hlssink?

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5, gstreamer

I'm new to GStreamer and I've been trying to build some simple pipelines using gst-launch-1.0. I'm having difficulty figuring out what elements need to go together. For example, I want to stream a webm video to a HTML5 video tag inside a browser. To open and read the file I think I need to use playbin:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/ubuntu/g-streamer-lively/skyrim.webm ...
```

Then to make the file available I use hlssink:

```
! hlssink max-files=5  playlist-root=http://10.12.9.3/ location=/var/www/html/hlssink.webm
```

Then in my browser I use the video tag:

```
<video src="http://10.12.9.3/hlssink.webm" controls>
```

So this pipeline won't start and I get the following error:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link playbin0 to hlssink0
```

So it tells me I can't link these two elements. Fine, but where do I look to find what other elements I need to include in my pipeline to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should stop and read a bit the gstreamer documentation to understand how it works. GStreamer is a framework for building a graph for data processing. You can find the manual here: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/index.html

Playbin is a special element (a bin) and it will assemble an internal pipeline for you. Playbin won't expose any linking pads as it is designed to create a full playback pipeline, that's why you can't link it to hlssink.

You can use other elements to create a pipeline to transcode your webm input to hlssink, for example you can use uridecodebin that is another bin that will automatically create a decoding pipeline for any media that you use (provided that you have the right plugins for it). Something like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=<youruri> name=decbin ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! tsmux name=muxer ! hlssink decbin. ! queue ! audioconvert ! faac ! muxer.
```

I haven't tested it, but something like that should work to convert your input to mpegts using H264 and AAC, for example, and pass the data for hlssink.

To check what elements you have on your system use the gst-inspect-1.0 tool. It will list all elements if you don't give it an argument or give you details about a particular element if you give it one, like:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 hlsssink
```

EDIT: fixing the pipeline you proposed in comments

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///home/ubuntu/g-streamer-lively/skyrim.webm name=decbin ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux name=muxer ! hlssink max-files=5 playlist-root=10.12.9.3 location=/var/www/html/hlssink decbin. ! queue ! audioconvert ! avenc_aac ! muxer.
```

Comment: So I have read through the documentation before but I still have a hard time figuring out the order of elements. Maybe it's because I don't have a background in video/audio editing so I don't really understand the process. If I just want to stream a .webm file why do I have to do things like videoconvert, x264enc etc. I can serve the .webm file directly to my browser via apache, why do I need to use these extra gstreamer elements to simply move the file through a simple pipeline?

Comment: I tried to use your pipeline and I had to change a couple of things: gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///home/ubuntu/g-streamer-lively/skyrim.webm name=decbin ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux name=muxer ! hlssink decbin. ! queue ! audioconvert ! avenc_aac ! muxer. ! hlssink max-files=5  playlist-root=http://10.12.9.3/ location=/var/www/html/hlssink.webm. Now when I try to start I get error: WARNING: erroneous pipeline: link without source element.

Comment: you're not "moving" a file through the pipeline, it will get processed at each node. When you use uridecodebin it will demux and decode your input file, assuming you have both video and audio you will get 2 outputs from it. Each one is getting reencoded with a new format to get muxed into mpegts that is usually what is served over HLS protocol that you wanted to use.

Comment: Your pipeline is wrong, there are two hlssink instances created and I'm not sure you understand what HLS is and how it works by the parameters you are selecting. HLS will create a playlist of small files to be download and played sequentially.

Comment: Hi thanks for the edit. I tried your new pipeline and I get the following error: ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/avenc_aac:avenc_aac0: Codec is experimental, but settings don't allow encoders to produce output of experimental quality. I tried to figure out where I can set 'experimental quality' but wasn't able to find it. Am I missing a flag or something?

Comment: Ok so I figured it out. Just need to set compliance=-2 right after avenc_acc: ... ! avenc_aac compliance=-2 ... I didn't find this in any of the documentation, just got lucky reading through a forum. Unfortunately I'm still not getting good results. This pipeline builds a file that is forever growing in size and my webpage with the <video> tag is still unable to play the video...

Comment: You need to properly set the hlssink properties to have it do a live HLS output. Check the gst-inspect-1.0 hlssink properties and set the according to your desired configuration. You are missing, for example, the target-duration for segments.